# Azure / VS Code / Hive / HDInsight - How to Stop Interactive Query

Tags: visual-studio, azure, hive, visual-studio-code, azure-hdinsight

I'm using VS Code to run Hive queries against an HDInsight machine in Azure.  One of my queries seems to have frozen.  Is there a way to stop the query (like the stop button in Sql Server SSMS)?

Comment: Did you try Ambari UI to stop the jobs? You can open Ambari Views from the Azure portal. Select your HDInsight cluster, and then select Ambari Views from the Quick Links section. From the list of views, select Hive View. Select the job and stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge, you cannot stop interactive query using VSCode.

Using VSCode, you can perfrom the following tasks:

- login
- List item
- logout list clusters
- Set default cluster
- Submit interactive Hive queries
- Submit Hive batch script
- Submit interactive PySpark    queries
- Submit PySpark batch script Set configuration

**Note:** You can stop interactive query from Ambari UI.